# Kendo-ui Scheduler Resource Template

Tags: jquery, vb.net, kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

I am using a vertically displayed resource to group my scheduler data. This is working perfectly but I however need to add the ability to click on the resource text and open a popup window.

All I need to do is add this but can't figure out how -

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="editRoute(#:RouteID#)">#:text#</a>
```

I do not see anywhere in the documentation about editing the client template for a resource. Any help would be great!

```
.Group(Sub(g)
      g.Resources({"Route"})
      g.Orientation(SchedulerGroupOrientation.Vertical)
End Sub) _
.Resources(Sub(r)
      r.Add(Function(m) m.RouteID) _
      .Name("Route") _
      .Title("Route") _
      .DataTextField("text") _
      .DataValueField("value") _
      .DataColorField("color") _
      .DataSource(Sub(d)
         d.Read(Sub(g) g.Action("GetRoutes", "Schedule").Data("getManagerID"))
         d.Events(Sub(e) e.RequestEnd("onRequestEndResource"))
      End Sub)
 End Sub) _
```

Here is a screenshot of the scheduler:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6O9zk.png]

Answer (score 2):

To see an example of Resource titles rendered as a link using templates:
http://dojo.telerik.com/eqUl

Source: http://www.telerik.com/forums/resource-grouping-title-template

Answer (score 0):

There are two options when it comes to this:

1. Find the element and override it with an OnClick event to do what you require. For example: `$(elementhere).onClick(function () { Action Here});`
2. Use kendo templates to override it. (However I'm unsure if you can modify the row headers.)

Comment: `$(".scheduler").find(".k-slot-cell").each(function () {
            var element = $(this);
            if (element != null) {
                
                if (element.context.textContent != " ")
                    YoureResources.forEach(function (resource, i) {
                        if (resource.Name == element.context.textContent) {
                            add click action
                        }

                    });
            }
        }
                );` somthing like this